# How does NodeJS behave with memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory, server

I am reading a book about NodeJS and the following example catches my attention:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

var tweets = []

app.listen('8000', '172.27.6.69', () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:8000`)

})
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to Twitter!')
})

app.post('/tweet', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body && req.body.tweet) {
        tweets.push(req.body.tweet)
        res.send({ error: false, message: 'Tweet received' })
    } else {
        res.send({ error: false, message: 'No tweet received' })
    }
})

app.get('/tweets', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ error: false, data: tweets, pid: process.pid })
})
```

If I publish the code on any server and several people try to make tweets, they are stored in the array tweets and anyone who makes a GET request can see all the tweets and we get the same PID. So, my question is: Does that data always remain in memory? Why does NodeJS share memory with all users? Why do we get the same PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the right questions. If only everyone starting out with node.js asked these questions!

> Does that data always remain in memory?

Yes, until either the process crashes, shuts down normally, or the data is garbage-collected due to your code not being able to reach it anymore, like if you overwrite the tweets array or something. To make data stick around—for example the ability to still have your data even if your process crashes and restarts—you'll need to use some kind of *persistence*, like a database or something which stores data on disk. Redis, MySQL, and MongoDB are examples of different persistence tools.

> Why does NodeJS share memory with all users?

There's no concept of users, or memory-per-user, in a node.js process. A single process has a memory address space which the whole process can see and use any way it sees fit, and the *same* process keeps running, serving request after request. The program executing inside that process is responsible to control who can see what data. For example, you can add session middleware to Express, which will give each user (identified by browser cookie) their own little private "stash" of data. If you did this, then you might have something like `req.user` which you could stick things onto like lists of tweets. Session data-stores can be in-memory, or (more commonly) backed by a persistence store like Redis or MongoDB.

> Why do we get the same PID?

This is because your server is apparently running inside a single node.js process. It's also possible to scale up your server by running a cluster of node.js processes within the same machine, with all processes "taking turns" serving incoming HTTP requests. If you did that, you'd start seeing different PIDs for different requests. You'd also see different tweets, since each process has separate memory (and thus its own separate `tweets` array), which they don't share with each other. Also, which tweets show up at any given time would be basically random, from the end user's POV. That's another reason why you can't rely on in-memory data stores, because you almost always want to scale across multiple processes, multiple machines, and even multiple data-centers and regions, but always serving a consistent set of data.

However, all of that said, it's perfectly fine and quite common to use in-memory data storage when experimenting and learning node.js. Once you get a feel for things, you can scale things up separately. It's just good to keep aware that in-memory storage can bite you if you try to scale up without understanding how memory works, hence these being great questions to ask.